# Get-AdminPowerApp -EnvironmentName Default-abcd-1234 fails when authenticating using client secret

Tags: powershell, power-platform

I registered an enterprise application using the steps mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/programmability-authentication

I am try to get a list of all Power Apps using PowerShell however it runs starts getting a few entries and then fails with:

```
 CreateAppObject : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AppObj' because it is null.
At C:\Users\apoorvak\
Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.167\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.Powershell.psm1:8953 char:41
+                 CreateAppObject -AppObj $app
+                                         ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [CreateAppObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,CreateAppObject
```

However, if I use - Username and Password instead of Client secret it works without issues.

```
CreateAppObject : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AppObj' because it is null.
At C:\Users\apoorvak\
Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.167\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.Powershell.psm1:8953 char:41
+                 CreateAppObject -AppObj $app
+                                         ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [CreateAppObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,CreateAppObject
```

Comment: There is more than one type of authentication : https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Identity/1.0.0/api/index.html

Comment: Same issue with both the clientsecret and certificatethumbprint

Comment: You my not of set a password : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12917